# For loop only shows last value of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

So I've got an object called "options" with these items in it:

```
var options = {
  assignments: ['involved', 'assignee', 'candidate'],
  assignment: ""
}
```

With a for loop, I'm trying to put the values from my array assignments in the assignment var, one by one. Then I'm using "options" with the new value as parameters for another function I'm calling inside my loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < options.data.assignments.length; i++) {
  options.data.assignment = options.data.assignments[i];
  console.log("value of i : ",i);
  console.log("value of options :",options);
  otherFunction(options);
}
```

I was expecting to see results like this :

> value of i : 0
>
> value of options : {assignment = "involved"...}
>
> value of i : 1
>
> value of options : {assignment = "assignee"...}
>
> value of i : 2
>
> value of options : {assignment = "candidate"...}

But instead I have something like this :

> value of i : 0
>
> value of options : {assignment = "candidate"...}
>
> value of i : 1
>
> value of options : {assignment = "candidate"...}
>
> value of i : 2
>
> value of options : {assignment = "candidate"...}

The thing is while doing that my assignment variable is always set to "candidate", the value at the end of my array.

The strange thing is when I'm trying to `console.log(options.data.assignments[i])`, the right value shows up. Same for the "i", it goes from 0 to 1 then 2 and stops properly. So my loop is working perfectly fine, except when I want to set the value of my variable.

Any ideas what's the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: `options.data.assignment = options.data.assignments[i];` makes no sense.... you are reassigning what you are looping over? It is going to be the last value because the loop ends at the last value.

Comment: When you assign to a variable, you replace the old value with the new value. What is it that you expect to happen?

Comment: @BlueWill : First of all It should be `options.assignments` and not `options.data.assignments`, assuming your snippet is correct.

Comment: what is your assignment variable supposed to look like after the loop?

Comment: is this merely typo or you didnt know the difference between `=` and `==` and `===`?

Comment: @BeingExpert it's normal, I voluntarily simplified my object for my question. It is indeed part of an other object called Data.

Comment: @BlueWill - nobody knows what you want `options.data.assignment` to actually be/contain after the loop. Please clear that up.

Comment: he asked why the data aren't the ones he needs, not how he would like the data to be

Comment: is `otherFunction` asynchronous by any chance?

Comment: If you make assumptions about what code is important and what code isn't, your assumptions may be wrong and you're just wasting people's time (and not getting the answer you need).

Answer (score 6):

```
for (var i = 0; i < options.data.assignments.length; i++) {
  options.data.assignment = options.data.assignments[i];
}
```

will loop 3 times:

1. `options.data.assignment = options.data.assignments[0]` -> `options.data.assignment='involved'`
2. `options.data.assignment = options.data.assignments[1]` -> `options.data.assignment='assignee'`
3. `options.data.assignment = options.data.assignments[2]` -> `options.data.assignment='candidate'`

So in fact, you are assigning 3 different data one by one to the same value, so, in the end `options.data.assignment` will be the last value of your loop.

Here is what you do with a easier example :

```
var a = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   a = i;
}
```

as you can see, in the end the variable `a` will always be the last value of the loop `i`.

First of all It should be `options.assignments` and not `options.data.assignments`.
Here is something you want

```js
var options = {
  assignments: ['involved', 'assignee', 'candidate'],
  assignment: ""
}

for (var i = 0; i < options.assignments.length; i++) {
  options.assignment = options.assignments[i];
  console.log("value of i : ",i);
  console.log("value of options :", options);
  // otherFunction(options);
}
```

Here is what i get :
[image]

As you can see, my assignment is changing

Comment: This is what I would like yes, when I do the console.log(options.assignment) I do get the same results as you, but when I do console.log(options) then assignment is set to "candidate" for all three iteration.

Comment: Not for me, there is something you do that you did not tell us (@BlueWill i edited)

Comment: Then I don't know. Because I can't reproduce your error i can't help you more than i already did

Comment: It's ok, I will look deeper in the code and find a solution eventually. Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning to the same var everything, replacing the previous values as you go along.
If you just want to concatenate all elements from the array to the string you can do this

```
for (var i = 0; i < options.data.assignments.length; i++) {
  options.data.assignment += options.data.assignments[i]+',';
}
```

EDIT: as said by @puzhi : 
You can also do this to take care of the last ',' without removing it after

```
options.data.assignment = options.data.assignments.join(',')
```

Comment: or even easier `options.data.assignment = options.data.assignments.join(',')` this will also leave of the last `,`

Answer (score 0):

you are reassigning same variable with each iteration in loop thats why last value gets assigned after third loop.

You can simply do this to achieve what you need.

```
 options.data.assignment = options.data.assignments.map(ele=>ele)
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP actually wanted to do

Comment: To be fair, it's completely unclear what the OP is trying to do, but it also doesn't make sense to guess at what they want and post your guess as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {
    assignments: ['involved', 'assignee', 'candidate'],
    assignment: ""
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < options.assignments.length; i++) {
    options.assignment += options.assignments[i]+";"; //updated the assignment operator to get desired result
  }
  console.log(options.assignment);
```

Comment: or even easier `options.data.assignment = options.data.assignments.join(';')` this will also leave of the last `;`

Comment: Yes. All I wanted to point out was that,  operator needed to be updated for getting the desired result.

Comment: Should have probably explained that in your answer rather than just a block of code. Can be difficult to spot the changes unless you know what you're looking for.